# Creating new PhpMyAdmin USER for MySQL Database. ERROR

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

i am using XAMPP v3.2.1 and i am working on a school project with an online system. since i am new to web development, i don't have even the slightest hint on how to do things. so i created a new user in PhpMyAdmin, i named it "administrator" and entered a password for it. and it was saved. i then created a new MySQL Database and tried to connect it to a simple php file. i used this line in connecting.

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","administrator","r00tadmin###","mjca_db");
```

and i am getting this error.

```
    Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'administrator'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SkyEngine\System\index.php on line 3
```

Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'administrator'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

i have no idea of what to do, i tried searching this on google but i dont know the correct syntax. i hope anyone can help me out. thanks

Comment: Did you call `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after you created the user? If not you should try this. If that won't work you might have set the wrong host while creating the user.

Answer (score 0):

i think username "administrator" is already precated word, try to use another username.
anyway check this tutorial if this helps you http://www.yourwebskills.com/dbphpmyadminusers.php

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, i found the answer. i located this file

```
    "C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php"
```

and open it. skipped to line 19 and change it from

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

i apologize for being lazy earlier. i found the solution myself. i hope this helps anyone else.

```
    NOTE: this also enables the login feature of PhpMyAdmin on XAMPP
```

Comment: In you question are talking about `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","administrator","r00tadmin###","mjca_db");` in the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\SkyEngine\System\index.php` this should not be related to settings in `phpMyAdmin`. Did you restart the computer the mysql server is on or the mysql server itself between the first  and this test?

Comment: i did not restart the computer. i tried restarting apache and mysql before editing the configurations and i had no luck. when i edited the config. it worked

Comment: Well if it really failed at the line `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","administrator","r00tadmin###","mjca_db");` then changing `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` could not be the reason why it works now. I still assume you didn't call `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after creating the user, which is required that the change will be _applied_ immediately. The `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` is used only by phpMyAdmin to determine how to connect to mysql. I would assume that phpMyAdmin now asks you for a password instead of doing an autologin. And that the problem was solved cause of the restart.